# Extract common files from two projects into a third project, preserving directory structure

Tags: python, node.js, bash, ubuntu

I would like to identify which files are common to both projects and copy those files into a third empty project. The comparison should be recursive and needs to account for file contents and path.

I need to copy the common files, preserving their path.

I am doing this to extract the common code from two projects into a common folder.

It's a react project. I am open to using any tool, library or language to accomplish this. I am imagining there is a straight forward way to accomplish this using an existing tool.

I have tried using meld which allows me to identify the common files, but has no way to copy them.

Comment: `which files are common to both projects` Do you mean same by filename or filecontent? Also if there's even a spacing different, most softwares might detect it as different if it is not written as perfectly as git is written

Comment: Same path and same content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the shell and unix core utils are good and fun for this:

```
dir1=<path to first project directory>
dir2=<absolute path to second project directory>
outdir=<path to new merged project directory>
# copy dir1 to outdir
cp -a $dir1 $outdir

# compare to files in dir2 
cd $outdir
find . -type f | while read path; do
  # path exists in dir2 and is not different, else delete it
  [ -e "$dir2/$path" ] && diff "$path" "$dir2/$path" >/dev/null || rm -f $path
done
```